# How to get serverID for Google Authentication

Tags: android, google-client, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

So I have 2 projects, and I need to merge them.
And in the one that I need to delete I have the following key, which works with GoogleSignInOptions:
[image]
Now, in my new project. I don't know how to create this.
It says that it is a Service account client, but the:
Create Credentials -> Create Oauth Client ID -> only gives me this options:

Web application
Android
Chrome App
iOS
PlayStation 4
Other

I tried, now there is a button: 
Create Credentials -> Service Account Key -> but this returns a different object, and still doesn't work. I tried it, but only with the App Engine Default Service Account.

But I am pretty certain I did not do it this way, when implementing the first time.
Then I did something that made me download a google-services.json, and then it also gave me the Server Client ID. I haven't worked with this in a while, so I'm lost. Am I doing something wrong?

This is my code:

```
String serverID = getString(R.string.server_client_id);
    Log.i("","handleSignInResult serverid: " + serverID);
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(serverID)
            .requestServerAuthCode(serverID)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to pick "other":

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It shows me this: 
07-20 10:12:41.382: E/TokenRequestor(1242): You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE
 I even tried with Android Key, but it asks for sha1, so I gave my debug one, but still doesn't work. It's weird how the other one has the Service account client type and this one doesn't

Comment: This worked, after I added my Android key, and enabled  Google Identity and Access Management (IAM) API